# Change ActiveRecord relationship on fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Suppose, I have a model

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_models
end
```

When some other code is loaded, e.g. some plugin or extension I want to modify this relation. I try this by just reopening the class:

```
class Model
  has_many :other_models, on_add: :method_on_add
end
```

But that doesn't work. It uses only the options for the first relation. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do metaprogramming; when some of your code is loaded; you can do as follow.

```
Model.class_eval do
  has_many :other_models
  # whatever you want to code
end
```

[here](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval) is a good tutorial on metaprogrramming